# Projection and preserve structure

Tags: xpath, subset, projection

for the following document

```
<root>
 <child no=1>
  <grandchild no=1></grandchild>
  <grandchild no=2></grandchild>
  <grandchild no=3></grandchild>
 </child>
 <child no=2>
  <grandchild no=1></grandchild>
  <grandchild no=2></grandchild>
  <grandchild no=3></grandchild>
  <grandchild no=4></grandchild>
 </child>
</root>
```

how can I select all children together with only their respective first two grandchildren? I.e. I'd like to return

```
<child no=1>
 <grandchild no=1></grandchild>
 <grandchild no=2></grandchild>
</child>
<child no=2>
 <grandchild no=1></grandchild>
 <grandchild no=2></grandchild>
</child>
```

My attempt `//child/grandchild[@no=1 or @no=2]` only gives me

```
 <grandchild no=1></grandchild>,
 <grandchild no=2></grandchild>,
 <grandchild no=1></grandchild>,
 <grandchild no=2></grandchild>
```

i.e. grandchildren are no longer contained in their respective children.

Many thanks for suggestions and pointers!
bb

Comment: Xpath is used to select the tag in the xml, not modify it. you want modify the `child` tag and xpath can not do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath is used to select the tag in the xml, not modify it. you want modify the child tag and xpath can not do it.

But you can use `lxml` or `xml` library to parse the xml and modify it.